# How to run web application from a console application in c#

Tags: c#

I have a web application which includes `aspx` and `cs` files. I want to write a console application to start the web application. But I do not know how to do that. Is is possible?

Comment: is the web application running on a server? or are you talking about it starting it from Visual studio?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without more information about what kind of web application it is, where it is hosted and so on.

Comment: it will run on a server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your website on a server (local or not). From your console application you can run the URL.

```
string url = "http://localhost:23423";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
```